# Algorithm for neuron activation order

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, algorithms

I'm developing a [JS library](https://github.com/wagenaartje/gynaptic) with the ability to create 'flexible' neural networks. Flexible meaning that they don't consist of layers, but merely of single neurons or neuron 'groups'.

I don't want to activate neurons layer by layer, as this does not give a lot of options for layer mutation/modification.

So I'm looking for an algorithm which decides the neuron activation order. Example of a neural net:

[image]

This is quite a complex net. But I want to decide the activation order of this neural network with an algorithm, of course I can figure it out myself, some of the correct orders are:

`1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`

`1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7, 10, 9`

`3, 5, 8, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10`

**I need an algorithm which returns a possible activation order!** Any hints?
*(The algorithm is given the connections between neurons.)*

---

But it gets more complex... say we have some short term memory:[image]

The algorithm should not take any connections that serve as memory into consideration. So these two added memory connections shouldn't alter the activation order!

Comment: For your future reference when you are writing papers for publication: apostrophe+s stands for is ("what's = what is", "it's = it is", "how's = how is", etc.) "get's" therefore does not make any sense (get is?)

Comment: You want to find some order or every possible order?

Comment: Topological sorting is probably what you need: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

Comment: I want to find the order with the least possible memory connections